# How to add new Class to only First DIV, In this JS structure

Tags: javascript, html

i have this text box when i add some lines from this text box then these lines added to something like this structure.

you can check this lines by Copy/Paste and insert to this textbox:

Question-1 : The color of the sky is...?

Question-2 : Paper comes from...?

Question-3 : How many hours in a day?

Question-4 : A Giraffe is a fish?

[image]

But now my need is that i want to add one extra class `answer` in only first line like this:

[image]

***My All JS Text box Code is that:***

```js
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
const textArea = document.getElementById('input');
const innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var message = textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // split the textarea entries into an array
  let lines = (textArea.value).split("\n");

  // iterate over each line, creating a div/span and inserting into the DOM
  lines.forEach( (line) => {
    let encodedLine = encodeHtmlEntity(line);
    let newElement = `<div class="quiz">${encodedLine}</div>`;
    
    innerDiv.innerHTML += newElement;
  });
  
  // reset the textarea
  textArea.value = '';

});

function encodeHtmlEntity(input) {
  var output = input.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
  });

  return output;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner"> </div>


<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
<button class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">add text</button>
```

How can i do that. plz solve my issue. What some extra lines of code i need to write ?

Thanks in Advance , Love You.

Comment: really very nice question.

Comment: The second parameter provided to the `forEach` callback function is the index of the current item, so with that you should easily be able to handle that first item differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an index and then using tha to conditonally add the class first

```
sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // split the textarea entries into an array
  let lines = (textArea.value).split("\n");

  // iterate over each line, creating a div/span and inserting into the DOM
  lines.forEach( (line,i) => {
    let encodedLine = encodeHtmlEntity(line);
    let newElement = i===0 ? 
    `<div class="quiz answer">${encodedLine}</div>` :
    `<div class="quiz">${encodedLine}</div>`
    
    innerDiv.innerHTML += newElement;
  });
  
  // reset the textarea
  textArea.value = '';

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure there always be, at least one "quiz" class element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('quiz')[0].classList.add('answer')
```

The `[0]` represents the **first** element with the "quiz" class.

---

*Note: if there is no "quiz" class element at all, then:*

```
document.getElementsByClassName('quiz')[0] === undefined
```

*wil be true and the line will throw an error like this:*

```
Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to add the class directly while the div elements are created. Your proposed solution works for element that are already present in the DOM.

Comment: Ahhh, I may have misinterpreted the question, sorry. I understood that the need was "how to add" the class to the element, not how to get it born with both classes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
  // iterate over each line, creating a div/span and inserting into the DOM
  lines.forEach( (line, index) => {
    let encodedLine = encodeHtmlEntity(line);

    let classList = 'quiz';
    if (index === 0) {
      classList += ' answer'
    }

    let newElement = `<div class="${classList}">${encodedLine}</div>`;
    
    innerDiv.innerHTML += newElement;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('classYouNeedToFind')[0]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('classYouNeedToFind')[0].classList.add('classYouNeedToAdd');
}
```

The if is just to avoid errors if there is no element with the class. And in jQuery

```
$('.classYouNeedToFind').eq(0).addClass('classYouNeedToAdd');
```

No if needed in jQuery.